# Firebase Firestore - Compare data from 2 collections

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a problem with my firebase database. I would like to be able to retrieve and compare the content of 2 different collections. In this case I want to check that the user's answer is the same as the answer of the answer key which is in another collection. The problem is that I think the queries are done asynchronously, so I can't save the value outside the docRef.get() function. Thanks in advance for your help.

Below is where I get the user's answer :

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
         if (user) {
             var uid = user.uid;
             document.getElementById("useruser").innerHTML = user.displayName;

              var docRef = db.collection("Quiz").doc(user.displayName);
              docRef.get().then(function(doc) {
                    if (doc.exists) {
                       console.log("Document data:", doc.data());
                       document.getElementById("question1_1").innerHTML = doc.data().Question; //Here I have my user's answer
                       document.getElementById("reponse1_1_1").innerHTML = doc.data().Reponse1;
                       var lisetRep = doc.data().Reponse1;
                       document.getElementById("reponse1_1_2").innerHTML = doc.data().Reponse2;
                       document.getElementById("reponse1_1_3").innerHTML = doc.data().Reponse3;
                       document.getElementById("reponse1_1_4").innerHTML = doc.data().Reponse4;
                    } else {
                       // doc.data() will be undefined in this case
                       console.log("No such document!");
                    }
              }).catch(function(error) {
                    console.log("Error getting document:", error);
              });



        } else {
           window.location.href="account-connexion.html";
        }
     });
```

Below is where I get the corrected answer

```
var docRef = db.collection("ReponseJ").doc("ReponseJuste");
                  docRef.get().then(function(doc) {
                        if (doc.exists) {
                           console.log("Document data:", doc.data());
                           document.getElementById("question1_1").innerHTML = doc.data().Question; //Here I have the corrected answer
                           document.getElementById("reponse1_1_1").innerHTML = doc.data().Reponse1;
                           var lisetRep = doc.data().Reponse1;
                           document.getElementById("reponse1_1_2").innerHTML = doc.data().Reponse2;
                           document.getElementById("reponse1_1_3").innerHTML = doc.data().Reponse3;
                           document.getElementById("reponse1_1_4").innerHTML = doc.data().Reponse4;
                        } else {
                           // doc.data() will be undefined in this case
                           console.log("No such document!");
                        }
                  }).catch(function(error) {
                        console.log("Error getting document:", error);
                  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to [chain the promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises#chaining), and make the values captured in the first `then()` block available in the second `then()` block as follows. I've used an Array but you can use any other equivalent method.

```
      var answerArray = [];

      docRef
        .get()
        .then(function (doc) {
          if (doc.exists) {
            answerArray.push(doc.data().Reponse1);
            answerArray.push(doc.data().Reponse2);
            answerArray.push(doc.data().Reponse3);
            answerArray.push(doc.data().Reponse4);

            console.log('Document data:', doc.data());
            document.getElementById(
              'question1_1'
            ).innerHTML = doc.data().Question; //Here I have my user's answer
            document.getElementById(
              'reponse1_1_1'
            ).innerHTML = doc.data().Reponse1;
            var lisetRep = doc.data().Reponse1;
            document.getElementById(
              'reponse1_1_2'
            ).innerHTML = doc.data().Reponse2;
            document.getElementById(
              'reponse1_1_3'
            ).innerHTML = doc.data().Reponse3;
            document.getElementById(
              'reponse1_1_4'
            ).innerHTML = doc.data().Reponse4;

            // See the return below
            return db.collection("ReponseJ").doc("ReponseJuste").get(); 

          } else {
            // doc.data() will be undefined in this case
            console.log('No such document!');
            throw new Error('...');
          }
        })
        .then(function (doc) {
          if (doc.exists) {
              // Here compare the answers and the correct responses
              // For example
              if (answerArray[0] === doc.data().Reponse1 && answerArray[1] === doc.data().Reponse2 && ...) {

              }
          }
        }
        .catch(function (error) {
          console.log('Error getting document:', error);
        });
    } else {
      window.location.href = 'account-connexion.html';
    }
  });
```

Comment: At the second .then(), before comparing I do a console.log(doc.data()), but I get undefined. I don't understand.

Comment: Are you sure there is a doc corresponding to `db.collection("ReponseJ").doc("ReponseJuste")`? Do you have  read access to it (no security rule preventing the access)?

Comment: Oh I feel like a real jerk, I'm so sorry, the document name was missing a character. Anyway, thanks for everything.

Comment: It happened to every developer ;-)